# Using for loops to create reversed numbered lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I have this function.

```
def creates(n): 
    output = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        output.append(range(-1, i-1))
    return output
```

I want it to return `[[1],[2,1],[3,2,1],[4,3,2,1]]` when I print creates(4) without using a reverse function in the code. I know it's possible and I feel like I am using append incorrectly but I don't know where the issue is. Thanks!

Comment: Your expected output is Python 2.X specific. Can you tag it so? Because Python 3.X returns range objects in result.

Comment: [Are you asking almost the same question each time ?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3000645/user3000645)

Answer (score 6):

You mean to do:

```
output.append(range(i, 0, -1))
```

Since `range(4, 0, -1)` (for example) returns `[4, 3, 2, 1]`.

Note that this could be written in fewer lines as a list comprehension:

```
def creates(n):
    return [range(i, 0, -1) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```